# Какая разница между двумя строками кода?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Помогите разобраться, какая разница между этой строкой:

```
current_user.money = 20
```

и этой:

```
current_user.update(money: 20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одна полностью включает в себя эффект другой.

```
current_user.update(money: 20)
```

...аналогично:

```
current_user.money = 20
current_user.save
```